# Is there a way to get the query results (rows affected/time taken) after every query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I run multiple MySQL queries together in phpMyAdmin, I basically want to be able to see the results of each query (rows affected/time taken etc) as it completes. Say I have the following sample queries

```
UPDATE PC1 SET `A1` = 'C1' WHERE `A1` = 'B1';
UPDATE PC1 SET `A2` = 'C2' WHERE `A2` = 'B2';
UPDATE PC1 SET `A3` = 'C3' WHERE `A3` = 'B3';
```

When I run these and say a few more what happens is at the end of the third/last query I get the results together

```
163 rows affected. (Query took 0.0015 seconds.)
445 rows affected. (Query took 0.0065 seconds.)
779 rows affected. (Query took 0.0215 seconds.)
```

I currently use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` but I would like to be able to see the query results as they complete.

Is there a way to for me to run all of the queries together and see the query results as they complete?

I want to run the above three update queries. I can run it one by one, run the first one and wait for it to complete, review the rows affected/time taken and then run the second and wait for it to complete and the same for the third. Alternatively, I can just write all three together and wait for all of them to run and complete. I am doing the second, however what happens is all of the three run together and at the end of the third, I see the rows affected for all three together. I am trying to see if I can see the output of each query as it completes. In reality, I have tens of queries.

I get all three stats, however I get all of them at once on completion of the third query. I am trying to see if I can get the stats as they complete, say first query completes and I get the stats on screen instead of waiting for all three to complete and then seeing all three stats at once.

Answer (score 1):

You send **one** command, **one** line (which consists from 3 queries). So PHPMyAdmin waits until this command finished, and then shows the result of this one command which consists from 3 separate results. I think he has this feature - it is PHPs input buffering.

Use CLI interface, for example - it shows the result for each query in a command immediately after this result is formed and sent to server's output / client's input. - [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)